# does wordpress serve static files?

Tags: performance

I am debugging an issue with WordPress and I wonder if static files like css/images/js are affected by WordPress/PHP or if they are served directly by apache?

I do not have any WordPress cache plugin active at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually: no.
When WordPress is running on apache with mod_rewrite enabled, it'll use

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

To make sure that static files will **NOT** be served through WP.
A plugin might add its own rewrite rules to the .htaccess, but generally WP will not interfere with static files, those will be dealt with by apache directly.